# Can't run geoproject from d3-geo-projection

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to follow Mike Bostok [tutorial](https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-1-897aa8f8ca2c#.c9rgmkcf1). Every time I want to run geoproject I obtain the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/d3-geo-projection/bin/geoproject:5
    d3 = Object.assign({}, require("d3-geo"), require("../")),
                ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/d3-geo-projection/bin/geoproject:5:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks